# Power amplifier design for increasing output current and reducing output impedance of a function generator

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-amplifier

When I use a function generator to feed a common mode LC filter (L = 200 μH in common mode, C = 2nF) with 1 MHz, 10 Vp-p, I observed that the function generator was unable to supply that much load.

So I am planning to design a power amplifier (basically, a current amplifier) with the following specification:

- Frequency range: 0-10 MHz (or at least 0-5 MHz)
- Output voltage: 10 Vpp
- Maximum output load: at least 2 A

The input current is expected to be very low as it will be fed from a simple function generator (max. output current is not specified in the function generator manual, but I think it should be less than 30 mA).

If you have any idea about how to design one, please suggest!

Comment: Most function generators have outputs with 50 ohm source impedance. To maintain signal integrity, their outputs should be terminated by a 50 ohm load impedance. So it's not true that "the input current is expected to be very low". Not at all. At 1Vrms open circuit output voltage from the generator, the current will be 10mArms. At 10Vrms, the input current will be 100mArms (!). *max output current is not specified in the function generator manual, but I think, they should be less than 30mAmp* It's not a matter of a guess - it is directly related to the voltage and load impedance. Both are known

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica noone forces yugi to use parallel termination for a 10 MHz sine wave. Can well use series termination into a very high impedance input. With a short cable.

Comment: For this power level and bandwidth, I suppose a Class AB output with BJTs will be the simplest option. I usually advocate Class D, but for a 10 MHz bandwidth, you would need extremely high switching frequencies.

Comment: You might do well to examine function generator schematics, looking specifically at their output stage(s). Very few (if any) are capable of 2A current, but these amplifiers exhibit quite low output resistance. The generator has a well-defined "50-ohm" output resistance only because of a big, fat 50-ohm resistor between amp output and the output terminal. Were you to short-out this resistor, more current would be available - **but the amplifier has serious risk of overheating when driving your series-L-C resonator, at resonance**.

Answer (score 1):

A Class AB should do fine. Make sure, the opamp has enough GBW product.

The transistors must be well cooled. Small emitter resistor can help to avoid bias current runaway. Class AB is not easy with heat playing a role, but I believe that Class D will be even harder in this case and Class B will ruin your nice generator waveforms.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPziEe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>